# How do i move Azure DNS to godaddy?

Tags: azure, azure-dns

I have purchased a domain in Azure portal. I have access to DNS Zone in Azure portal and i can add/remove DNS records. Now i want to move the domain including all records to Godaddy. I do not find any option in the Azure portal for it. How do i migrate to Godaddy?

Comment: My advise. Do not move your DNS server to Godaddy - there is no good technical reason that I can think of. You will need to manually create each resource record at GoDaddy and then change/recreate the NS resource records to point to Godaddy's DNS servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If I understood right, you would like to transfer away your domain from Azure/GoDaddy to another registrar. You may check below steps in case missed anything.

1. Go to the Azure Portal.
2. Navigate to the domain (not the DNS zone, but the App Service Domain)
3. You should see in the menu an option that says **“Advanced Management Portal”**
4. This will take you to GoDaddy. Select the desired domain name you would like to transfer by clicking on it directly to access the domain settings page.
5. Under Additional Settings, select Transfer domain away from GoDaddy.
6. Review the transfer checklist, then select Continue with transfer. If your domain ends with .UK, you'll need to enter the IPS tag for your new registrar, then select Complete Transfer.
7. Select Click here to see Authorization Code, then Copy to Clipboard to copy your authorization code. We'll also send an email with your auth code to the administrative email address on your domain name.
8. Select My Domains to go back to your list of domains.

Also, You'll need to finish the transfer process with your new registrar and provide them with the authorization code for your domain name.

Note that you can’t transfer your domain if its within 60 days of registration or a previous transfer, if a 60-day lock was applied after updating domain contact information, or if your domain has Ownership Protection.

**Suggestion:** Contact GoDaddy Customer Service for quick help and to save some money.