# Transfer Azure DNS to another provider

Tags: azure, dns

I am having trouble figuring out how to transfer Azure DNS to another provider. All web searches show how to migrate to Azure but not transferring out.

Answer (score 0):

- *In Azure portal Open your Domain services*
- *Then go to Advanced Management Portal*
- *Now open your Domain and unlock yur domain first*
- *Then go to domain settings and select Remove Domain by Proxy*
- *Now if you scroll down a bit you will find remove domain protection*
- *Also there you will find an option of transfer domain away from Azure*
- *Then you will be generated with EPP code that need to be presented at new provider*
- *After intiating transfer within 24 hours you need to open Advanced Management portal again and select Transfer option*
- *Finally your Domain will be transferred to different provider.*

[image]

You can check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70194278/how-do-i-move-azure-dns-to-godaddy) for related discussions.