# Transfer DNS from Azure DNS to different registrar

Tags: azure, azure-dns

I am have a couple domains that are using azure as the registrar and Azure DNS to host the zones. I have request from a customer to move these to a different registrar. When I go into the Azure portal, I don't seem to have any option under "App Service Domains" or the DNS zones themselves to unlock the domain for transfer.

I have read on a few places that there should be a link for "advanced dns management" and from there I can unlock the domain which will allow the transfer to be initiated from the new registrar (ie: GoDaddy). However, I don't have any such link.

I originally transferred these domains to azure from a different registrar a few years ago. I used a powershell script to do that. I am wondering if that is why I might not get the normal options as these resources were created a little differently.

Is there a PowerShell script to unlock the domain so I can do this transfer?

Thank you in advance!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to check the **`Advanced Management Portal`** option and was able to find it in my environment as below:***

[image]

**Alternatively**, try using [**Domain Manager (secureserver.net)**](https://dcc.secureserver.net/domains)  as suggested in this [Microsoft QnA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/198331/i-cannot-access-advanced-management-portal-1.html) by **ajkuma-MSFT**.

- Make sure to have **Administrator or Co-Admin role** on your subscription.

Try **unlocking** the domain by *selecting your domain-> Advanced settings* like below:

[image]

> **If your domain is within 60 days of registration or a previous transfer, you cannot transfer the domain as mentioned in this [**blog**](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/09/22/2021-Managing-ASD.html#transfering-domain-out) By Yutang Lin.**

*If the issue still persists, please raise [**Azure Support Ticket**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/) for the same.*

**To Transfer DNS from Azure DNS to GoDaddy, please try the following:**

- Go to Advanced Management Portal.
- Select the domain name you want to transfer.
- Under Additional settings, select the **`Transfer`** option based on your requirement.
- Select continue to transfer and enter the IPS tag for the new registrar and complete transfer.
- Copy the authorization code and select My Domains.
- Enter the authorization code for the domain name.

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[How to unlock my domain if "Advanced Management portal" in App Service Domain greyed out by Noman Latif](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/651880/how-to-unlock-my-domain-if-34advanced-management-p.html)

[How do i move Azure DNS to godaddy by Pramil Gawande](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70194278/how-do-i-move-azure-dns-to-godaddy)