# How to Access a custom domain outside azure which I bought in azure portal

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

ok so I bought a custom domain within azure portal for my website. but now that my msdn subscription is over in azure I want to move my website to some other service or a cheaper solution as it is just a static website to show my video player app and I dont wanna purchase expensive subscriptions for it.

As I am searching for a solution regarding moving my website to another new azure account or outside azure to somewhere else I am trying to find where can I access my domain ownership outside azure portal? Because I assume on the backend azure must be using some service to purchase the domain right? as per portal renewal to my domain is still pending till next year so I technically still own that domain and I wanna keep my website on it live, just dont wanna pay for expensive azure subscription.

> it is just a static website with ssl certification service applied on it for https.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have bought custom domain using Azure portal then you may want to know that App Service Domains use GoDaddy for domain registration and Azure DNS to host the domains. In addition to the yearly domain registration fee, usage charges for Azure DNS apply.

For information, see [Azure DNS Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/dns/).

In your case you can transfer away your domain and Transferring of domain out of Azure (not a registrar) to another registrar is supported and you may currently do so via API and PowerShell.

You will need to get an authorization code which you can take to the registrar of choice to proceed with transferring out of your domain.
You can use the transfer out API:

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION-ID>/resourceGroups/<RESOURCE-GROUP-NAME>/providers/Microsoft.DomainRegistration/domains/<DOMAIN-NAME>/transferout?api-version=2021-02-01
```

You may be able to run this API on [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/raw/).

Check [this blog](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/09/22/2021-Managing-ASD.html#transfering-domain-out) for more details on this.

Also check this [similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70194278/how-do-i-move-azure-dns-to-godaddy) here might be help.